# Как из одного массива получить три новых, чтобы элементы в них были взяты из исходного с определённым шагом?

Tags: python, массивы

Например, есть такой массив:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ,12]
```

Нужно получить три таких:

```
a1 = [1, 4, 7, 10]
a2 = [2, 5, 8, 11]
a3 = [3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: так в заголовке уже половина ответа написана

Comment: Только начал писать на питоне и не знаю, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: a1, a2, a3 = [a[x::3] for x in range(3)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про срезы

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

a1 = a[::3]
a2 = a[1::3]
a3 = a[2::3]

print(a1, a2, a3)
```